# How to fix ‘SQL stored procedure’ error in ASP.Net to show two Select result in Chart column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to link stored procedure to ASP.net Chart with two select query to show result in many series. This for my web application, running against SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2015.

I've tried to link chart series to stored procedure but I can't show this two results on the ASP chart datasource. The results contain first select statement only.

```
SELECT
    User_.[User_name],
    CONVERT(INT, ROUND(SUM((Result.Evaluation_data) * 100) / (10 * (COUNT(Result.Evaluation_id))), 0)) AS InTeam
FROM 
    Result 
INNER JOIN 
    User_ ON Result.Evaluated_user_id = User_.[User_id] 
WHERE 
    (Result.Evaluation_id = 1 OR Result.Evaluation_id = 2)
    AND result.Evaluation_did_user != Result.Evaluated_user_id
    AND Result.Evaluated_user_id IN (SELECT [user_id] FROM user_ 
                                     WHERE user_.team_code = 1)
    AND Result.Evaluation_did_user IN (SELECT [user_id] FROM user_ 
                                       WHERE user_.team_code = 1)
GROUP BY
    User_.[User_name]
ORDER BY
    User_.[User_name]

SELECT
    User_.[User_name],
    CONVERT(INT, ROUND(SUM((Result.Evaluation_data) * 100) / (10 * (COUNT(Result.Evaluation_id))), 0)) AS OutOFTeam
FROM 
    Result 
INNER JOIN 
    User_ ON Result.Evaluated_user_id = User_.[User_id] 
WHERE 
    (Result.Evaluation_id = 1 OR Result.Evaluation_id = 2)
    AND result.Evaluation_did_user != Result.Evaluated_user_id
    AND Result.Evaluated_user_id IN (SELECT [user_id] FROM user_ 
                                     WHERE user_.team_code = 1)
    AND Result.Evaluation_did_user IN (SELECT [user_id] FROM user_ 
                                       WHERE user_.team_code != 1)
GROUP BY
    User_.[User_name]
ORDER BY
    User_.[User_name]
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Hi Michael no errors but i can't show this two results on the ASP chart datasource

Comment: only the results contain first select statment only

Comment: Share your code for binding chart to multiple results set.

Comment: What does "can't" mean? Please explain the actual problem. If you're just trying to stick those two datasets together, use `UNION ALL` or a join

Comment: i want to see select results like that user_name inteam user_name outofteam

Comment: my question in another way Bind 2 SQL DataSource to a single chart

Comment: Thanks I found the answer
with cte_ as